# How to make a button that changes video's playstate?

Tags: javascript, html, video, autoplay

I wanted to make a joke website and rickroll my friends, but I can only make a video autoplay with muted sounds. So I thought of making a fake cookie consent button that changes the video playstate (basically a button that plays the video)

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `video.play();`, assuming `video` is the video element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function videoPlay() {
    var video = document.getElementById('myvideo');
    var btn = document.getElementById('playBtn');
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
        btn.innerHTML = "Pause"
    } else {
        video.pause();
        btn.innerHTML = "Play"
    }
}
```

```html
<video id="myvideo" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    <button id="playBtn" onclick="videoPlay()">Play</button>
```

Comment: This answer is definitely right, I've had pretty much the same script, but it still wasn't working and I looked into the console. I didn't link the JS file...